# $.ajax fires success when not async; error when async?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I've got an $.ajax doing a PUT onto an API endpoint .

When the 'async' option is true the error handler fires for FF/Chrome but not for IE.

When 'async' is false but the success handler fires for all three browsers .

What could be causing this ?

I've stripped both JS and C# down to the minimum and it currently looks like this .

The JS code  :

```
function _saveClickHandlerFactoryTESTBED(rtrnToSmplDtlsURL){
return (function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/templatesetallocationcontroller/updatesampletemplatesetselection',
        type: 'PUT',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {},
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        async: false,
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log("Success !")
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("Error !")
        }
    });
});
};
```

And elsewhere in the JS

```
$('#btnsave').bind("click", _saveClickHandlerFactoryTESTBED( rtrnToSmplDtlsURL ));
```

The C# just sends a 200 response under all circs :

```
    [System.Web.Http.Route("api/templatesetallocationcontroller/updatesampletemplatesetselection/")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPut]
    public HttpResponseMessage UpdateSampleTemplateSetSelection([FromBody]JObject jsonbody)
    {
        try
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "OK");
        }
        catch (Exception ae)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

In fiddler I can see the 200 response coming back ...

[image]

... but when in FF/Chrome the error handler is fired not the success handler.

Due to something else I read on Stackoverflow I tried changing the Ajax invocation so that it was synchronous and it appears this makes the success handler fire for all three browsers !

Any ideas on why the different browser / synch-asynch behaviour ?

I should come clean and confess the jQuery version is 1.11.x which is a couple of years old.